# Insert random string into each instance of whitespace

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, random

I'm trying to insert a randomly selected string into each instance of whitespace within another string.

```
var boom = 'hey there buddy roe';
var space = ' ';
var words = ['cool','rad','tubular','woah', 'noice'];
var random_words = words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)];

for(var i=0; i<boom.length; i++) {
  boom.split(' ').join(space + random_words + space);
}
```

Output comes to:

```
=> 'hey woah there woah buddy woah roe'
```

I am randomly selecting an item from the array, but it uses the same word for each instance of whitespace. I want a word randomly generated each time the loop encounters whitespace.

What I want is more like:

```
=> 'hey cool there noice buddy tubular roe'
```

Thanks for taking a look.

(This is beta for a Boomhauer twitter bot, excuse the variables / strings )

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can use regex instead however, you are not seeing the result you desire because you are randomly selecting one word and then replacing all occurrences of a space with it.

The regular expression below replaces occurrences of a space with a dynamic value returned by a callback. You could compare this callback to your for-loop but instead, it's iterating over the spaces found and by doing so you can replace each occurrence with a 'unique' random word.

```js
const boom = 'hey there buddy roe';
const words = ['cool', 'rad', 'tubular', 'woah', 'noice'];
const random = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);

let replace = boom.replace(/ /g, () => ` ${words[random()]} `);

console.log(replace);
```

Comment: I think your answer is the one that works best, however explaining your code would be helpful, especially for OP and people not familiar with ES6.

Comment: Yep, just wanted to get my answer up first

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that `random_words` is set to a single word.

Try this instead:

```
var boom = 'hey there buddy roe';
var words = ['cool','rad','tubular','woah', 'noice'];

boom.replace(/ /g, (space)=> space + words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)] + space);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the effect you desire, you need to do the word selecting inside the loop, not outside of it.

```
for(var i=0; i<boom.length; i++) {
    // get a new number every loop
    var random_words = words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)];

    boom.split(' ').join(space + random_words + space);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What is wrong with OP's code: random_words is initialized once only, with a random word. Intention there is, however, to select random word for every whitespace encountered instead.

You can either go with:

```
for(var i=0; i<boom.length; i++) {
   boom.split(' ').join(space + words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)] + space);
}
```

... or make random_words a *function* that returns a random word, then call it in your 'boom' loop. With every call, a new word selection will occur.

Answer (score -1):

You need to recalculate the random word on each loop. Right now you have picked out a single random word, stored it in the `random_words` variable, and you reuse it each time. You could modify your code like this:

```js
var boom = 'hey there buddy roe';
var space = ' ';
var words = ['cool','rad','tubular','woah', 'noice'];

function getRandomWord() {
  return words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)];
}

// Uses the same because the value given to join is not recalculated each time:
console.log(boom.split(' ').join(space + getRandomWord() + space));

// You could do this with a standard for loop:
let result = "";
let split = boom.split(' ')
for(var i=0; i<split.length; i++) {
  result += split[i] + space;
  if (i === split.length - 1) break;
  result += getRandomWord() + space;
}

console.log(result);

// Or you can use a reduce:
let otherResult = boom.split(' ').reduce((res, word, index, split) => {
    if (index === split.length - 1) return res + space + word;
    return res + space + word + space + getRandomWord();
});

console.log(otherResult)
```